# Python, Overriding an inherited class method

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, super, overwrite

I have two classes, `Field` and `Background`. They look a little bit like this:

```
class Field( object ):
    def __init__( self, a, b ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.field = self.buildField()

    def buildField( self ):
        field = [0,0,0]
        return field

class Background( Field ):
    def __init__( self, a, b, c ):
        super(Background, self).__init__( a, b )
        self.field = self.buildField( c )

    def buildField( self, c ):
        field = [c]
        return field

a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
background = Background( a, b, c )
```

This error is pointing to Field's `buildField()`:

```
"TypeError: buildField() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)."
```

I expected Background **init**() to be called first.  To pass "a, b" to Fields **init**(), Field to assign a and b then to assign a list with three 0's in it to field.  Then for Background's **init**() to continue, to then call its own buildField() and override self.field with a list containing c.

It seems I don't fully understand super(), however i was unable to find a solution to my issue after looking at similar inheritance problems on the web and around here.

I expected behavior like c++ where a class can override a method that was inherited.  How can i achieve this or something similar.

Most issues I found related to this were people using double underscores.  My experience with inheritance with super is using the inherited class **init**() to just pass different variables to the super class.  Nothing involving overwriting anything.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> I expected Background init() to be called. To pass "a, b" to Fields
>   init(), Field to assign a and b

So far, so good.

> then to assign a list with three 0's
>   in it to field.

Ah. This is where we get the error.

```
    self.field = self.buildField()
```

Even though this line occurs within `Field.__init__`, `self` is an instance of `Background`. so `self.buildField` finds `Background`'s `buildField` method, not `Field`'s.

Since `Background.buildField` expects 2 arguments instead of 1,

```
self.field = self.buildField()
```

raises an error.

---

So how do we tell Python to call `Field`'s `buildField` method instead of `Background`'s?

The purpose of [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) (naming an attribute with double underscores) is to solve this exact problem.

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.field = self.__buildField()

    def __buildField(self):
        field = [0,0,0]
        return field

class Background(Field):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(Background, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.field = self.__buildField(c)

    def __buildField(self, c):
        field = [c]
        return field

a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
background = Background(a, b, c)
```

The method name `__buildField` is "mangled" to `_Field__buildField` inside `Field` so inside `Field.__init__`,

```
    self.field = self.__buildField()
```

calls `self._Field__buildField()`, which is `Field`'s `__buildField` method. While similarly,

```
    self.field = self.__buildField(c)
```

inside `Background.__init__` calls `Background`'s `__buildField` method.

Comment: Use a "mangled" method as a public method, I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: In this case, is there any way to call Field's buildField method from Background?

Comment: Answer my own question, user `super().buildField()`.

Answer (score 31):

Coming from a C++ perspective, there might be two misconceptions here.

First, a method with the same name and different signature does not overload it like in C++. If one of your Background objects tries to call buildField with no arguments, the original version from Field will not be called -- it has been completely hidden.

The second issue is that if a method defined in the superclass calls buildField, the subclass version will be called. In python, *all* methods are bound dynamically, like a C++ `virtual` method.

Field's `__init__` expected to be dealing with an object that had a buildField method taking  no arguments. You used the method with an object that has a buildField method taking one argument.

The thing with `super` is that it doesnt change the type of the object, so you shouldn't change the signature of any methods that the superclass' methods might call.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish would need you to type check self in the Field.__init()__(self, a, b):
It's not pythonic, but would allow you decide which signature you wanted to call.

Answer (score 18):

> I expected Background init() to be called

Actually `Background init()` is getting called..

But **take a look at your Background class..**

```
class Background( Field ):
    def __init__( self, a, b, c ):
        super(Background, self).__init__( a, b )
        self.field = self.buildField( c )
```

So, the first statement of `__init__` is invoking the `super class(Field)` init method.. and passing the `self` as argument.. Now this `self` is actually a reference of `Background class`..

**Now in your Field class: -**

```
class Field( object ):
    def __init__( self, a, b ):

        print self.__class__  // Prints `<class '__main__.Background'>`
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.field = self.buildField()
```

Your `buildField()` method is actually invoking the one in the Background class.. This is because, the `self` here is instance of `Background` class(Try printing `self.__class__` in your `__init__` method of `Field class`).. As you passed it while invoking the `__init__` method, from `Background` class..

**That's why you are getting error..**

> The error "TypeError: buildField() takes exactly 2 arguments (1
>   given).

As you are not passing any value.. So, only value passed is the implicit `self`.

Answer (score 5):

The `super(Background, self).__init__( a, b )` will invoke:

```
def __init__( self, a, b ):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.field = self.buildField()
```

in `Field`. However, `self` here refers to the `background` instance, and `self.buildField()` is in fact calling `buildField()` of `Background`, which is why you get that error.

---

It seems to be that your code should be better written as:

```
class Field( object ):
    def __init__( self, a, b ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.field = Field.buildField()

    @classmethod
    def buildField(cls):
        field = [0,0,0]
        return field

class Background( Field ):
    def __init__( self, a, b, c ):
        super(Background, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.field = Background.buildField(c)

    @classmethod
    def buildField(cls,c):
        field = [c]
        return field

a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
background = Background( a, b, c )
```

If you can't allow the base constructor to finish then it signals that the design is flawed.

It is therefore much better to separate `buildField()` to belong to the class by using [`classmethod` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) or [`staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod), if you *have to* call these methods in your constructor.

However, if your base class constructor does not invoke any instance method from within, you can then safely overwrite any method of this base class.

Answer (score 1):

`Overriding` is talked about but it sounds like to me `chaining constructors or (methods)`

And also it sounds like **over-writing** properties:

Let me explain:

- A property named **field** will be initialized as `[0,0,0]`.
  `@property` decorators looks better fit.
- Then, `Background` class **over-write** this property.

---

#### Quick and Dirty Solution

I do not know your business logic but sometimes by-passing super class's `__init__` method gave me more control:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Field( object ):
    def __init__( self, a, b ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.field = self.buildField()

    def buildField( self ):
        field = [0,0,0]
        return field

class Background( Field ):
    def __init__( self, a, b, c ):
        # super(Background, self).__init__( a, b )
        # Unfortunately you should repeat or move initializing a and b
        # properties here
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self.field = self.buildField( c )

    def buildField( self, c ):
        # You can access super class methods 
        assert super(Background, self).buildField() == [0,0,0]
        field = [c]
        return field


a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
bg = Background(a,b,c)
assert bg.field == [2]
```

---

#### Using properties

Has more clean syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Field( object ):

    @property
    def field(self):
        return [0,0,0]


    def __init__( self, a, b ):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Background( Field ):
    def __init__( self, a, b, c ):
        super(Background, self).__init__( a, b )
        self.c = c

        assert  (self.a, self.b, self.c) == (0,1,2)  # We assigned a and b in 
                                                   # super class's __init__ method

        assert super(Background, self).field == [0,0,0]
        assert self.field == [2]

    @property
    def field(self):
        return [self.c]


a, b, c = 0, 1, 2

background = Background( a, b, c )

print background.field
```

Answer (score 0):

PayCharm reports the warning:
`"Signature of method 'Background.__buildField()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'Field'`
I got around this warning by adding Optional[int] as the type hint `c: Optional[int] = None`.

```py
from typing import Optional


class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.field = self.__buildField()

    def __buildField(self):
        field = [0,0,0]
        return field


class Background(Field):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(Background, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.field = self.__buildField(c)

    def __buildField(self, c: Optional[int] = None):
        field = [c]
        return field


a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
background = Background(a, b, c)
```