# How to pass XGBoost fit parameters when using OneVsRestClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgbclassifier

I want to pass the fit's parameters of `xgboost` through `OneVsRestClassifier`'s fit method.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier( XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', seed=0))
# Want to pass `eval_set` and 'eval_metric' to xgboost model.
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, estimator__eval_metric='aucpr', estimator__eval_set= eval_set_xgboost)
```

> Error: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'estimator__eval_metric'

Can you please help me how can I pass the `XGBoost` fit parameters using `OneVsRestClassifier` fit method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XGBoost` by default handles the multi-class classification. Refer to [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/multiclass_classification/train.py) example for more explanations.

With the current framework, you cannot pass `fit_params` for `OneVsRestClassifier`. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10882) for more details.

May be, if you can share your intention for wrapping with `OneVsRestClassifier`, we can guide you appropriately.

## Update:

I don't think wrapping with one Vs rest classifier would reduce the overfitting.

Use the simple XGBoost but fine-tune the hyper-parameters.

- First choice would be reducing the learning rate while increasing the number of iterations of training.

The other best options for reducing the overfitting is briefed [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/param_tuning.html#control-overfitting)

Comment: In the dataset, I have four classes. I want to try OneVsRestClassifier in which estimator is XGBoost. For avoiding overfitting, I need to pass the fit parameters.

Comment: I have a highly imbalanced dataset. I need to use `sample_weight`, do you have any idea how can I pass this parameter when using `OneVsRestClassifier `?

Comment: I again stress that using `OneVsRestClassifier` will not improve the model performance. Try changing the parameters on the base xgboost itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of iterations"? Which parameter in XGBClassifier is this?

Comment: It is the `num_boost_round` param in `train` method

Answer (score 1):

I have recently running to this issue to pass pos_scale_weight dynamically, and below is how I work around the solution. There is currently no automatic pos_scale_weight available for the XGBClassifier class. And we really want to use sklearn OneVsRestClassifier with xgboost for multi-label or multi-class classification problems.

A common way of using OneVsRestClassifier is as below:

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(XGBClassifier(booster='gbtree', objective='binary:logistic'))
clf.fit(X=X_train, y = y_train)
```

What it OneVsRestClassifier does is:  when you call clf.fit, it actually calls the fit method from XGBClassifier to fit X_train, and each target from y_train to fit the training data. In the example below, the clf.fit method is going to: XGBClassifier.fit(X_train, target1) ->  XGBClassifier.fit(X_train, target2) -> XGBClassifier.fit(X_train, target3) -> ensemble all three models. If you set the pos_scale_weight to a certain number then each fit will be using the same scale. If the positive ratio across the all three targets are widely different. It will under-fit the target whose positive rate is way lower than the others.

```
y_train.head()
| target1| target2 |target3|
|--------|---------|-------|
| 0      | 1       | 0     |
| 1      | 1       | 0     |
```

In my challenge, each label I am predicting has a totally different pos and neg ratio(range from 0.1% to 10%). Below is a method I created. Assume we have X_train as training features, y_train is a matrix of binary labels for each class. We can work around and create a new class that inherited the fit function and pass a weight_array for each array of y_train. OneVsRestClassifier will pass each y from y_train one by one, therefore the weight_array will be calculated separately. This solution is only for binary classification([0,1]) for multi-label. We want to make sure the neg class's weight is 1, pos class's weight to be the (num of neg)/(num of pos).

```
class XGBClassifierNew(XGBClassifier):
      """
      the inherited class with same method name will override.
      if you start an XGBClassifierNew instance the fit method you called by default will be XGBClassifierNew.fit(). Check the link below for reference.
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764995/python-overriding-an-inherited-class-method
      """  
      def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
          pos_ratio = y.sum()/len(y)
          weight = len(y)/y.sum() - 1
          weight_array = y * (weight-1) + 1
          return super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight = weight_array, **kwargs)

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(XGBClassifierNew())
clf.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
```

And the reason why weight_array is an array is because sample_weight takes weight for each instance rather than entire class like pos_scale_weight.

And this method treats entire class's weight(within each label) equally same.

Comment: This is answer to posted question.@Basil

Comment: Could you check whether the contribution by hogius in the other answer is valid? I quote it, in case it gets deleted: weight_array = y * weight + 1
(otherwise you give 0 weight to the negative class...) end of quote

Comment: @Yunnosch hey I have checked hogius's answer. he is right, need to change the equation for weight_array so we have some smoothing here. y*weight + 1 can be one of the option. I will update my answer.

Comment: @hogius thank you for the answer. I will update the answer accordingly, however y*weight + 1 might not be the most accurate value. Please check my update later.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Chandler Sekai is helpful. One line needs to be changed however:

`weight_array = y * weight + 1`
(otherwise you give 0 weight to the negative class...)

Comment: this answer might have been better, if you added in the full answer from Chandler Sekiai because, for me, it's confusing to see one change to code change, but not in the content of the original answer.

Comment: You have spotted a potential improvement in somebody else's answer which even got validated by that author (in spite of the hint of possibly being not optimal). Though you are a new contributor you were extremely careful not to show their work as yours. With that attitude you should soon make reputation elsewhere. Have an upvote on this answer, for being useful. I hope it does not get misunderstood later, when the other answer is updated. I write this to make other users aware of the history of this post. Good luck.